# TextView scroll to last location

Tags: android, scroll, textview

I want to return to certain location in a textview.
For example, I have a textview, scroll to a certain location (% of text or to a line).
I want to capture that location, and then when open same textview with same text and same font size, I want to return to same location.

What are the commands to get location and scroll to that location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not an editable text box you may be best off using a TextView wrapped in a ScrollView, and then using getScrollX() and getScrollY() to find the postion, and scollTo() to restore.  Be aware however that setting the scroll position can be a bit funky. See: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/1a36f62df821d771

Comment: there is no need to use ScrollView - scrollTo(x, y) is View's method and could be used directly on any view - TextView in this particular case (considering the time the question was asked, I have to add that this is about api 11+)